# Error while executing zf.sh in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, sh

In *Zend Framework 2*, I added the library directory  to php include_path. But when I run zf.sh I get the following errors:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Tool\Framework\Client\Console\Console' not found in /var/www/html/zend/bin/zf.php on line 611

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Tool\Framework\Client\Console\Console' not found in /var/www/html/zend/bin/zf.php on line 611
```

I checked Library/Zend directory and there is not any directory named *Tool*.

Is there any extra step I should do?

Comment: Did you delete some directories in the original ZendFramework folder you downloaded?

Comment: No! I think this issue: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-84 is related to this problem

Comment: PHP-CLI uses a different php.ini, than Apache's PHP -- `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` vs `/etc/php5/apache/php.ini`. Are you sure you changed the correct one?